# String modifying and replacing c#

Tags: c#

I have a string like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />
```

Now, I want to just extract "/abc/def/ghi/default.css" and pass it to a function foo

```
void foo(string str)
{

//some logic
return str; //suppose it returns /abc/def/ghi/default.css/v=123
}
```

And i want to append it back to my original string like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css/v=123' type='text/css' media='screen' />
```

i tried with substring, but alwals the content changes and i can start looking string from "href" but i dont know how long will the href be.

Comment: Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: I want in c# code

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is a nuget package you can add to your code.  It handles parsing HTML for you.  So you dont have to roll your own.

Comment: that is c# or JS ? method in c# can not start with "function"

Answer (score 0):

Still you can play with substring if you identify the start and end single quote after the 'href' identifier in the string.

```
public string foo(string inputString)
        {
            string result = "";
            int hrefIndex = inputString.IndexOf("href=");
            int firstQuoteIndexAfterHref = -1;
            int secondQuoteIndexAfterHref = -1;

            if (hrefIndex != -1)
            {
                firstQuoteIndexAfterHref = inputString.IndexOf("'", hrefIndex + 1);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("hrefIndex={0}, firstQuoteIndex={1}", hrefIndex, firstQuoteIndexAfterHref);
                if (firstQuoteIndexAfterHref != -1)
                {
                    secondQuoteIndexAfterHref = inputString.IndexOf("'", firstQuoteIndexAfterHref + 1);
                    result = string.Format("{0}/v=123",inputString.Substring(firstQuoteIndexAfterHref, secondQuoteIndexAfterHref - firstQuoteIndexAfterHref + 1));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: And i again want to append it to <link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css' type='text/css' media='screen' /> . SO changing <link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css' type='text/css' media='screen' /> to <link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css/v=123' type='text/css' media='screen' />

Comment: First put an id attribute, ex. <link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css' type='text/css' media='screen' id="link1"/>, then in the code behind on some button action or page load event handler put link1.Href = link1.Href + "/v=123";

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that:

```
public string foo(string str)
{
    var StartIndex = str.IndexOf("href");
    var firstapostrophe = str.IndexOf("'",StartIndex);
    var secondapostrophe = str.IndexOf("'", firstapostrophe);
    var result = str.Replace(str.Substring(firstapostrophe, secondapostrophe - 2),
    str.Substring(firstapostrophe, secondapostrophe - 2) + "/v=123");
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: And i again want to append it to `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />` . SO changing `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />` to `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/abc/def/ghi/default.css/v=123' type='text/css' media='screen' />`

Comment: so you can use the `Replace()` method, please see my changes in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply treat it like xml, take a look at this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "<link href='aaa' />";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
        var link = doc.Element("link");
        var href = link.Attribute("href");

        href.Value = "bbb";
        s = doc.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```